# What are pros and cons storing JSON in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

In my current project, my DBA suggested to store everything as JSON object in oracle. I don't feel that is the right approach because basically he suggested to use Oracle like MongoDB. Is there any Pros and Cons storing JSON objects in Oracle database as it is RDBMS database.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDB/json.htm#ADXDB6246

Comment: That really sounds strange

Comment: Can you give us an example of what you mean by "store everything as JSON object"?  Theoretically you could store all your data inside a single JSON value, using only one column in one table.

Comment: He'll probably create JSON column as CLOB/BLOB. This makes table hard to maintain. like extract will work only using Oracle tools. Limitation on one CLOB column. Inability to copy CLOB via Ddblink, etc.

Comment: @thank you all. Yes this is what my response was

Comment: It may seem very convenient for some application that consumes JSON, but it will become less so when you need to produce a normal report about monthly sales totals or whatever and you are stuck with a monumental string parsing task to extract the data.